# Canadian Tourist Visa - What's happening with my application?

Tags: visas, canada, application-status

I am an international student in the US and had applied for a Canadian Tourist visa. I got a confirmation letter with an IRCC code and the letter instructed me to go to any ASC or VAC to give my fingerprints and photograph.

I booked an appointment and went to Boston's Application Support Centre (although I live in a small city in NY - I was in Boston for a few days and decided to give it there since there were no centres very close to my home city either). When I left the Boston centre after giving my biometrics, the staff there told me to look out in my email for any further info. I haven't received anything since - it's been5-6 days and I'm not able to contact the centre either.

I don't mind if it takes a few more days, but I need to know what's happening with it, are there any further steps and very importantly, do I have to give my passport for stamping (if so where)? Any help on how to find this information would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/application/check-processing-times.html, processing times for tourist visas submitted in the US are up to 26 days.

Information on how to check the status of your application is here http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=052&top=3